# why do some apps not appear when adding app to home screen?

Tags: home-screen

I have HTC Desire HD. I want to add an app (ColorNotes) to the home screen to quickly launch it. But when I try to add it, it is not in the Apps list. Is there a way to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long tap the ColorNotes app, then it should be in the Home Screen. Let me know if you already tried this.